# .htaccess RedirectMatch is OK to remove part from url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect this url:

```
domain.asd/category/node123/attachment/file123
```

to this one:

```
domain.asd/category/node123
```

by removing the `attachment/fn1aa` from the end.

Only the `node123` and the `file123` are dynamic.

The code below working, but it's valid, safe and resource-friendly?

```
RedirectMatch permanent category(.*)attachment /category/$1
```

Any recommendation are welcome. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/category/([^/]+)/attachment /category/$1
```

It's more strict and won't duplicate forward slashes (`/`). Your regex will also match things like this:

```
domain.asd/foo/something/category/a/b/c/d/e/f/some-attachment
```

by redirecting to:

```
/category//a/b/c/d/e/f/some-
```

which probably isn't what you want to do. It's safe and as resource friendly as it is using an htaccess file (which is slight performance hit as opposed to putting this in the vhost config).